# GCP Composer (Airflow) - passing parameter to job dynamically

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jinja2, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a requirement wherein i need to pass parameters to an Airflow dag (eg. tenantName), and the airflow dag(python operator) will use the tenantName to filter data based on the parameter passed.

i'm able to access the parameters stored in Airflow , using the following code

```
    def greeting():
        import logging
        logging.info("Hello there, World! {} {}".format(models.Variable.get('tenantName'), datetime.datetime.now()))
```

However, for my requirement - the tenantName will differ depending on the run.
How do i achieve this ?

Comment: With regards to your requirement, where will you be getting the `tenantName` dynamically? Will `tenantName` be generated by a function, operator, etc.?

Comment: @RiccoD - i'm planning to read the tenantName(or customerName) from a Mongo collection, and then would like to run the DAG individually for each customer/tenant .. pls let me know if you have inputs on this .. thnx